# How to replace the SQL Server cursors with While loop / User Defined Functions

Tags: sql-server, cursor, user-defined-functions

I happened to see this : Cursors are sometimes used to perform a calculation on values that come from each row in its rowset. This scenario can also be achieved by replacing a Cursor with a User Defined Function. Can anybody give a possible scenarios ?

Also,how the while loop being used to replace the cursor

Comment: Please provide a specific example of your code

Comment: Cursor is weapon of last resort. I could bet that 90% of cursors could be replaced with set based solution.

Comment: Replacing a cursor with a while loop is an exercise in futility. What you should focus on is replacing your cursor with a set based solution.

Comment: Always found cursors to be cumbersome, especially when we have CROSS APPLY, TVF, and SVF

Comment: To expand on @SeanLange 's comment: Cursors and While loops both loop. SQL Server excels at set-based operations. I MAYBE end up having to write a cursor or a loop once or twice a year, and even then I've carefully exhausted set-based solutions.

Comment: No one is going to provide you with any specifics until we know what the cursor is doing now. If you'd like actual help on a specific challenge, please post the cursor code and some test data (in the form of CREATE TABLE & INSERT statements).